# Extjs4, how to retrieve single textfield value?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

```
var confirmWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
     title: 'Selected Item List',
     autoHeight: true,
     width: 500,
     layout: 'fit',
     modal: true,
     items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        bodyPadding : 5,
        items: [{
           xtype: 'textfield',
           id : 'freightFee',
           fieldLabel: 'Freight Fee ',
           name : 'freight' // I need this value, when I click the button
        }]
     }],
     bbar: ['->', {
         xtype: 'buttongroup',
         items: [{
           text: "test",
           handler: function () {
              // I want to get the textfield value (freightFee)
              var freightFee = Ext.getCmp('freightFee').getValue(); // error :Ext.getCmp('freightFee') is undefined
                }
            }]
            }
        });
```

I have a window like above, and I want to get the text inputbox value when I click the button.

I tried,

```
var freightFee = Ext.getCmp('freightFee').getValue();
```

but error message say,

> Ext.getCmp('freightFee') is undefined

anybody know this?

thank you!

Comment: FYI your code is missing a closing `]` to end off the bbar array, other than that, I ran your code against Ext 4.1.0 and it gets the value as I would expect.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't use `getCmp` ever! It's very expensive and unnecessary. Check out `up/down` methods to locate elements parents/childrens http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-down

In your case something like that should work:

```
handler: function(button) {
   var tf = button.up('window').down('#freightFee');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your command, I tried with your code, but still there is an error, error message say : button.up('window') is undefined. could you help me out one more time plz?

Comment: Downvote for don't use getCmp `ever`. In some instances it's perfectly valid to use. Also, it's not expensive at all, it's just a hash lookup, much cheaper than up/down/child.

Comment: Whatever dude... Plain array lookup through hundreds/thousands elements - sure. My position - don't use it _ever_. It's not necessary.

Comment: No, it's not an array lookup through elements, it's a `hash` lookup, by the id. Using if statements aren't necessary either, you could just use switch statements all the time, but you still do it. There are many valid scenarios where it is useful, saying you should never call an available method is rather single minded.